# Link Error In Android Studio When Trying To Use open62541

Tags: android, opc-ua

I am brand new to Android Studio. I'm trying to create an OPC UA client. When I try to compile I get an error like:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: UA_ClientConfig_default
```

for any open62541 functions. I've added open62541.c and .h to the cpp directory.
To CMakeLists.txt I've added:

```
add_library(
        open62541-lib
        SHARED
        open62541.c)
```

but I must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: Was able to fix by adding open62541 to target_link_libraries() in the CMakeLists.txt file
'''target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        open62541-lib
        android
        log)'''